# Understanding the proof of Excercise 10b from chapter 5 of Spivak’s Calculus.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

The question is “Prove that the limit as x approaches zero of f(x)=the limit as x approaches a of f(x-a).

I have taken a few stabs at the problem and was told that the solution was the image I attached.

The given proof largely makes sense to me, only it seems to be a proof that the limit as x approaches a of f(x) equals the limit as y approaches zero of g(y-a). I don’t see how this is a proof of what was asked, and I also don’t see how to proceed in the other direction. I think my issue is that I’m struggling to connect my intuitive/verbal understanding with epsilon-delta limit notation, and changing the variable from x to y also confuses me. Can anyone help make sense of this?

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L\iff$$ $$ \forall e>0\,\exists d>0\, \forall x\,(0<|x|<d\implies |f(x)-L|<e)\iff$$ $$ \forall e>0\, \exists d>0\,\forall x'\,(0<|x'-a|<d\implies |f((x'-a))-L|<e) \iff$$ $$ \lim_{x'\to a}f(x'-a)=L \iff$$ $$ \lim_{x\to a}f(x-a)=L.$$ Regardless of whether or not $a$ is a $0$ of $f.$

Comment: Ah, thank you. So my confusion was due to the fact that the proof was more general than I was expecting. Also, I’m new here; how do I post with nice notation like you?

Comment: On the top bar, right, click on Help. Choose the Help Center. Click on "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?"  Read it and its linked Quick Tutorial.

Comment: You can also look at MathJax.Org. This site has MathJax in it. E.g.  typing a dollar sign before  and after \lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L\iff gives $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=L\iff$.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you should not 'answer' with a question. This would be more suited for a comment.

Comment: @MathsofData: This was posted as an answer last year, but replaced by an unrelated question by a new user. Unfortunately, two users *approved* this edit suggestion.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet why does the author state that $|f(y+a)-l|<\varepsilon$ can we written as $|g(y)-l|<\varepsilon$? $g(x)=f(x-a)$, not $f(x+a)$.

Comment: Hi. I dont quite get the last equivalence. Why can we change from x' to x?

Comment: @Mangostino . Well, what are $x$ and $x'$ anyway? In the Middle Ages they would write  "The function of the difference of the first quantity minus the second quantity as the first quantity approaches the second quantity" which is accurate but long. Today we just say $x$ and  $a$, or we  say $x'$ and $a ,$  or whatever. It's like changing from blue ink to black.